# Android SharedElement with ViewPage

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I try to use SharedElementTransition with ViewPage;
eg:Activity A to Activity B with viewpage;
but if i change the image in viewpage,SharedElementTransition do not work,even i changed the TransitionName together
tell me,Great StackOverFlow,how can i make SharedElementTransitionwork with viewpage?

Answer (score 0):

Each ViewPager child needs to have a different transitionName,and pass the transitionName to the next activity,set to imageview.